# If a monomorphism $f$ is also a regular epimorphism, then is it an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

As the title suggests, let $f$ be a monomorphism and a regular epimorphism. The second condition means that f is the arrow of a coequalizer of a pair of arrows $x,y: X \to Y$, from what I understood. If I'm not mistaken, $f$ being a monomorphism implies that $x=y$, since $fx=fy$, by definition of regular epimorphism. Then, we can consider the identity morphism $1_Y: Y \to Y$, which factors through $f$, by definition of coequalizer, so we get $1_Y = uf$. I believe that this shows that $f$ has a left inverse, but now I need to show that it has a right inverse, right? Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We then have $fuf=f$ and use that $f$ is epimorphism.

An alternative proof: since $x=y$, their coequalizer is clearly $1_Y$, which is determined up to isomorphism (in the slice category).

Comment: Understood! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is the coequalizer of $x$ and $y$, then $f \circ x = f \circ y$. If $f$ is furthermore monic, then $x = y$. But the coequalizer of two equal maps is an isomorphism - in particular, one example of the coqualizer of $x$ and $y$ is the map $1_Y : Y \to Y$, which is an isomorphism. And since coequalizers are unique up to unique isomorphisms, $f$ must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!